# Negative Response Unnecessary "Vote Up requires 15 Reputation"

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users, up-votes

Seems to me the "Vote Up" privilege is fine to be available only to users who have a little bit of reputation (asked and answered a few questions perhaps).

Further, it's fine to make that visible and obvious to new users, so they can be encouraged to participate.

However, when a new user attempts to up vote a question or answer, they get a big red box that reads:

> Vote Up requires 15 Reputation
>
> (click to dismiss)

Instead, can't a more positive mode of participation be given, by using green, or some other positive color, and changing the verbage such as:

> Vote Up requires 15 Reputation
>
> Consider [link]Finding this useful[/link]
>
> and [link]Gaining more Reputation[/link]

I was discouraged for a long time from participating because it seemed to me that reputation was hard-earned and I couldn't do it. I'm barely starting now, and on a place like stackoverflow, it is hard to ask new questions, or answer the ones that aren't answered immediately.

Comment: What in particular would that message link to? And 15 rep isn't all that big of a hurdle really.

Comment: And before you assume that people think your question is bad, please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: Isn't it orange? That's not red.

Comment: @Bart The message would link to the "Find this useful?" question which logged-out users can use. Also 15 rep can be a big hurdle simply for providing useful information, and there are a lot of folks who just read SO and never post, so one might hypothesize about exactly why that is (for better or worse).

Answer (score 7):

I really don't see the point.

> Instead, can't a more positive mode of participation be given, by
>   using green, or some other positive color

This is a bit of a contradiction. Red *normally* means stop / no, green the opposite <sup>1</sup>. It might be quite confusing for people if this were reversed. I'm certain I wouldn't like to be told I can't do something with a green box. I would immediately associate this with success, which would be wrong.

The benefit of red is that it's immediately associated with failure which increases the chances that someone will actually read the words on there, as you did. You then knew what you had to do in order to be able to perform the action you'd just attempted.

There *might* be a place to make the verbiage less terse but you're going to have to suggest something that'll:

- Fit into a little box
- Actually *mean* something. Don't forget that this is something that has to easily and quickly convey its meaning to a wide audience from all over the planet.

> I was discouraged for a long time from participating because it seemed
>   to me that reputation was hard-earned and I couldn't do it. I'm barely
>   starting now, and on a place like stackoverflow, it is hard to ask new
>   questions, or answer the ones that aren't answered immediately.

Really? You've been a member for 1 day. You have 18 reputation having asked only *one* question and answered a different one. I really don't see how it is that difficult or how this fits into your previous point.

As you've only been a member for a day you've only had opportunity to experience this for one day. You rose to the challenge; well done!

<sup>1. I'm sure there are places this isn't true.</sup>

Comment: "Really? You've been a member for 1 day." - I would assume he's been a lurker for much longer than the 1 day that he's actually been a member...

Comment: Quite possibly, but the OP would have seen a popup asking him to log in if they weren't registered; so this doesn't really have a bearing on the first half of the question. The actuality of the OPs experience is different to that stated in the question.

Comment: Indeed, I have been a lurker for quite some time. As for the color green, sure, how about something other than green that is not red? The critique here is my post has a flaw of omission, in other words, the proper solution. This is a difficult question. I don't think there is an obvious solution. But I point to solutions like the "fail whale" of Twitter, where there is a concerted design effort to evoke empathy with users. I simply believe the format of providing feedback on SO questions could be more empathetic to the benefit of newbs.